# Windows system tray application not running from windows service and task schedular

Tags: c#, windows, windows-services

I have a windows service to create a process which will run a windows desktop GUI application, but service cannot run an application with UI.
I then moved to task schedular to run my windows UI application but unfortunately the exe starts in background and there is no UI in foreground. I can see a process running in task manager in both the case, task schedular and windows service.

Is there a way i want to run a windows desktop system tray application to run as soon as the machine starts.

Thanks!

Comment: Yes.  have it in the run list.. or use the task scheduler to run it on logon....

Comment: Can Task Schedular run a windows application with UI?

Comment: Yes, as long as you set it correctly - although there maybe a GPO that blocks it by default it is available

Answer (score 0):

you can try to put the application in the run registry for example.
if i am not mistaking the task scheduler is preventing interactive system tray items.

[See this article for more info about this option](http://vlaurie.com/computers2/Articles/startupreg.htm)